# How to obtain an "indirect implicant" in propositional logic

Tags: algorithm, logic, boolean-logic

I am trying to solve a problem in propositional logic that I don't think I have ever seen described anywhere. I am posting it here to see if someone has a hopefully standard solution for it.

Problem: given a propositional satisfiable logic formula `F` and a proposition `p` occurring in `F`, determine whether there is a satisfiable propositional formula **`phi` not containing** `p` such that

```
phi => (F => p)
```

and if so, provide such a phi.

For intuition, I would call `phi` an "indirect implicant of p wrt F", because it needs to imply `p` without mentioning p. Instead, it mentions other propositions that affect p through `F`.

Here's an example, where 'france', 'lyon', 'paris' and 'berlin' are all propositions:

```
F is "paris => france and lyon => france and berlin => not france"

p is "france"
```

Then a solution phi is `paris or lyon`, since that implies `(F => france)`

(Update: actually the precise solution is `(paris or lyon) and not berlin` because we did not state anywhere that these propositions are mutually exclusive, so `paris` and `berlin` (or `lyon` and `berlin`) could both be true at the same time and imply a contradiction. In the present of appropriate background knowledge the solution would be simplified to `paris or lyon`).

It resembles the problem of finding an implicant for the formula `(F => p)`, but it is not the same since a simple implicant can contain `p` (and in fact the prime implicant is simply `p`).

Again, I am posting it here in the hope that someone with more experience looks at it and says: "ah, but that's just a variant of problem such and such". That would be ideal as it would allow me to leverage existing algorithms (particularly satisfiability) and concepts.

Also, just for extra information, I am actually trying to solve this for equality logic, that is, propositional logic where propositions are equalities. That's of course more complex, but the propositional case may be a good stepping stone.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: For clarity, a few things need adjusting in your question I think. Your examples of F and p are not well formed. "France" is not a proposition. Perhaps use something like "I live in France".

Comment: Secondly, "determine the satisfiable propositional formula phi" is not quite right since there could be no such formula. And if there is one such formula then there are an infinite number of them. So perhaps "determine if there is a satisfiable propositional formula phi" is better.

Comment: Thanks. I did use the name 'france' for the proposition "I am in France" or some such. I added a comment to clarify. And you are right about the possibility of there not existing such a phi. In fact, perhaps a better, although harder to understand, formulation would be to drop the "satisfiable" requirement and only ask for the most general phi (false being only the most general one if there is not a satisfiable one, which would be more general than false).

Answer (score 1):

Given your example

```
F is "paris => france and lyon => france and berlin => not france"

p is "france"
```

Where `F` has 4 statements:

```
F1 = paris
F2 = france and lyon
F3 = france and berlin
F4 = not france
```

`F` can be decomposed, through simplifying implications `=>`:

```
F1-2: "paris => france and lyon" = "(not paris) or (france and lyon)"

F2-3: "france and lyon => france and berlin" = "(not france or not lyon) or (france and berlin)"

F3-4: "france and berlin => not france" = "(not france or not berlin) and (not france)"
```

And if we forward-chain through `F` implications, we will be doing reasoning:

```
Reason(F): not (not (not F1 or F2) or F3) or F4

not (not (not paris or (france and lyon)) or (france and berlin)) or (not france)
```

So, we have the following solutions:

```
S1: not france

S2: not (not (not F1 or F2) or F3):
     not (not (not paris or (france and lyon)) or (france and berlin))
```

Next we can evaluate `p` where:

```
p: france => france = TRUE

S1 = not france = not TRUE = FALSE ~ not applicable

S2 = not (not (not paris or (france and lyon)) or (france and berlin))

   = not (not (not paris or (TRUE and lyon)) or (TRUE and berlin))

   = not (not (not paris or lyon) or berlin)

   = not ((paris AND not lyon) or berlin)

   = not (paris AND not lyon) AND not berlin

   = not (paris AND not lyon) AND not berlin

   = (not paris OR lyon) AND not berlin
```

So, for `p` to be TRUE in `F` you need these conditions to be `TRUE`:

```
pF1 AND pF2:

pF1 = (not paris OR lyon) = (paris,lyon) in { (F,F), (F,T), (T,T) }

pF2 = not berlin => berlin = FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my own solution. I had posted the question hoping to learn of a standard solution, but perhaps there is not one.

1. Convert `F` to an equivalent DNF formula (Disjunctive Normal Form), that is, a disjunction of conjunctions `F1 or ... or Fn`, where each `Fi` is a conjunctive clause. A conjunctive clause is a conjunction of literals, where a literal is either a proposition or its negation. Conversion of a formula to DNF is a standard procedure.
2. For each disjunct `Fi`. It is in one of three forms:

   - `L1 and ... and Lmi and p`
   - `L1 and ... and Lmi and not p`
   - `L1 and ... and Lmi` (`p` does not occur in it).

   Let `inputs(Fi)` be the conjunction `L1 and ... and Lmi`, and `output(Fi)` be `true`, `false`, and `neutral` respectively.

   The intuition is that, if `Fi` were the only disjunct in the DNF of `F`, then if `inputs(Fi)` holds we need `p` to have the truth value `output(Fi)` (`neutral` meaning it could go either way) for `F` to hold.
3. The catch is, of course, that `Fi` will typically not be the only disjunct. For a given disjunct `Fi` without output `true`, there may be a disjunct `Fj` with a distinct output such that `ìnputs(Fj) and inputs(Fi)` is satisfiable, that is, there is an assignment to the inputs of `Fi` that satisfy `Fj` as well, and therefore admit `p` to be false while still satisfying `F`.
   We therefore name the disjuncts with output `true` `G1, ..., Gk` and disjuncts with output `false` or `neutral` `H1, ..., Hl`, and define `phi` to be

   ```
   (inputs(G1) or ... or inputs(Gk)) and not (inputs(H1) or ... or inputs(Hl))
   ```

Then `phi` is the solution because it does not contain `p` and implies `F => p`. It does not contain `p` because it is formed out of `inputs`, defined not to contain `p`. It implies `F => p` because it satisfies at least one of the `inputs(G_)` and does not satisfy any of the `inputs(H_)`. This means that, of all the disjuncts in the DNF of `F`, only the `Gi`'s  have a chance of holding true (all their literals but `p` are already known to be satisfied). Because they all contain `p`, if `F` is true then it must be the case that `p` holds as well.

Let's see how this manages the example given.

The DNF of

```
paris => france and lyon => france and berlin => not france
```

is

```
(not berlin and france) or
(not lyon and not paris and not france)
```

We therefore have

- `G1` equal to `not berlin and france`
- `H1`equals to `not lyon and not paris and not france`

so

- `inputs(G1) = not berlin`
- `inputs(H1) = not lyon and not paris`

and therefore `phi` is

```
not berlin and not (not lyon and not paris)
```

which is equivalent to

```
(lyon or paris) and not berlin
```

The presence of `not berlin` in the solution is not intuitive. It is there because `F` admits that more than one of `berlin`, `paris` and `lyon` be true at the same time. So, while requiring that either `paris` or `lyon` be true, it also requires `not berlin`, or otherwise both `france` and `not france` would be implied. In the presence of background knowledge stating that at most one variable be true at the same time, the solution would be simply `lyon or paris` since that would automatically imply `not berlin`.